# Why are my Alexa Skills Kit dependencies missing?

Tags: java, maven, alexa-skills-kit

I cloned Amazon's ASK java repository on github and ran 
    `mvn package`
on it, and it produced the following .jars:

```
ask-sdk-core-2.3.4.jar
ask-sdk-apache-client-2.3.4.jar
ask-sdk-dynamodb-persistence-adapter-2.3.4.jar
ask-sdk-lambda-support-2.3.4.jar
ask-sdk-servlet-support-2.3.4.jar
ask-sdk-2.3.4.jar
```

I noticed that when attempting to make certain imports for classes on https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills, such as 
 `import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.SpeechServlet;` 

I received a message stating that com.amazon.speech could not be resolved, indicating that the file didn't exist. However, after further investigation, I noticed that there was a SkillServlet class that seemed to essentially replace the SpeechServlet class as it was able to do everything that SpeechServlet could,
 so I assumed that the developer site hadn't been updated yet to reflect the changes. 
 I then noticed that `RequestHandler`, a class in the repository, had a method that returned an object of type `Optional< Response >`. When I tried to import `Response` with the following import:
`import com.amazon.ask.model.Response;`
I recieved an error message stating
 `The type com.amazon.ask.model.Response cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files` 
This suggests that the class definition doesn't exist in the project's classpath, despite having included all of the above .jars. I searched through and was unable to find a model directory. Did my maven build fail, and am I missing any .jars? I'm using Eclipse EE IDE, which I know is susceptible to errors, but I've cleaned my project as well as restarted the IDE to no avail.

Update:
I noticed that the pom.xml file within the ask-sdk-core-2.3.4 directory contained a dependency for ASK SDK Model, but it doesn't seem to be obtaining the dependency. I also noticed that though ask-sdk-2.3.4 should also include everything that ask-sdk-core-2.3.4 does, as the latter is listed as a dependency in the former, I have to include ask-sdk-core's jar file separately or Eclipse is not able to recognize certain classes. I think this means that maven has failed, so I just downloaded the jar directly from mvnrepository.com. Any idea why this might have happened?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ask-sdk-2.3.4.jar`, then it should include all the dependencies you need like you noticed in your update blurb. When you look at Hello World sample in their Github repo, the pom.xml only contains `ask-sdk-2.3.4.jar` but not other dependencies that `ask-sdk-2.3.4.jar` has in it. https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/blob/2.0.x/samples/helloworld/pom.xml

To your error message on `Response`, that is because you are missing ask-sdk-model jar which you can find from maven central. http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazon/alexa/ask-sdk-model/

I would suggest using maven and pom.xml so that you don't have to download jars individually.

Comment: I did use maven and the pom.xml when I ran 'mvn package'. Though it's different from using a maven build in that you have to manually add the jar files, it should still have the same effect after I add the jar files that 'mvn package' creates.